# How to use TLA+ to define sequential actions?

Tags: function, specifications, tla+

Say I have a simple set of sequential actions (which I will first define imperatively):

```
start(a, 1)
move(a, 3)
move(a, 5)
move(a, 4)
move(a, 2)
```

That is, we have a game piece `a` and start it at position `1`. Then we move it sequentially first to 3, then to 5, then 4, then 2. Once per step.

How would you define this using TLA+? Trying to wrap my mind around how to specify complicated *imperative action sequences* in TLA+.

Comment: Have you considered using PlusCal? Its a lot simpler to start from imperative PlusCal and see what it compiles to?

Comment: To expand on this and explain what PlusCal does: The PlusCal translator automatically creates a pc (program counter) variable in the TLA+ spec whose value is an enablement condition of the spec's actions and changed by the actions accordingly: `Start == pc = "start" /\ ... /\ pc' = "move"`.

Comment: Btw. StackOverflow is not the best place to ask TLA+ questions. The [user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tlaplus) and the [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tlaplus/) are far more active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviours sketched in the question could be described in TLA+ as follows:

```
---- MODULE Steps ----

VARIABLE a


Init == a = 1
Next == \/ /\ a = 1
           /\ a' = 3
        \/ /\ a = 3
           /\ a' = 5
        \/ /\ a = 5
           /\ a' = 4
        \/ /\ a = 4
           /\ a' = 2

Spec == Init /\ [][Next]_a /\ WF_a(Next)

=====================
```

The behavior of variable `a` is specified by the temporal formula `Spec` (other variables can behave in arbitrary ways).

The variable `a` starts equal to 1 (by the conjunct `Init`), and a temporal step either leaves `a` unchanged, or it changes it from 1 to 3. If this change occurs, then the following temporal steps either leave `a` unchanged, or change it from 3 to 5. The changes of value to `a` may continue until `a` equals 2. Further changes to `a` are impossible. Once `a` becomes equal to 2, it remains forever equal 2. These are the possible changes of `a`, as specified by the conjunct `[][Next]_a`, which means `[](Next \/ UNCHANGED a)`, i.e., `[](Next \/ (a' = a))`, with the symbol `[]` meaning "always".

The conjuncts `Init` and `[][Next]_a` specify a safety property. Safety is about what can happen, not what must happen. Liveness (what must happen) is specified with the conjunct `WF_a(Next)`, which describes weak fairness. The formula `WF_a(Next)` requires that if a step that satisfies the formula `Next` *and* changes the value of variable `a` is *enabled* uninterruptedly, then such a step must eventually occur.

In other words, if it is possible to change variable `a` by taking a step that satisfies `Next` (a `<<Next>>_a`-step), then `a` cannot remain forever unchanged, but must eventually change in a way that is described by `Next`. Indeed, while `a` is not 2, but 1, 3, 5, or 4, action `<<Next>>_a` (which means `Next /\ (a' # a)`, i.e., `Next` and `a` changes value) is enabled, so `a` will keep changing until it reaches the value 2. When `a` is 2, `<<Next>>_a` becomes disabled.

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of ways to do this, but here are two simple solutions which spring to mind; the first uses a macro:

```
---- MODULE Steps ----

VARIABLE a

move(start, end) ==
    /\ a = start
    /\ a' = end

Init ==
    /\ a = 1

Next == 
    \/ move(1, 3)
    \/ move(3, 5)
    \/ move(5, 4)
    \/ move(4, 2)

Spec ==
    /\ Init
    /\ [][Next]_a

=====================
```

Note the above will only work as long as your sequence of moves doesn't return to the same state. If it does, you'll have to add something like a `pc` "program counter" variable and a sequence and yada yada yada... at that point you're probably better off using PlusCal, a TLA+ variant which often works better for writing sequential actions:

```
---- MODULE Steps ----

(* --algorithm Steps
variables a = 1;
begin
    a := 3;
    a := 5;
    a := 4;
    a := 2;
end algorithm; *)

=====================
```

This has to be translated into TLA+ before it can be run by TLC. Use

- `CTRL+T` in the TLA+ toolbox
- `Parse module` command in the VS Code extension
- `java pcal.trans Steps.tla` with the CLI